# «Не» со словами категории состояния

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Я так и не могу разобраться, когда частица «не» пишется слитно со словами категории состояния, а когда раздельно. Вопросы будут не про все слова, а про некоторые из них.

Вроде пишем раздельно, когда между «не» и СКС можно поставить «было», «стало» и тд. Например: «На улице не холодно» — можно поставить «было». Тогда:

> На улице было нехолодно.

"Было" уже стоит перед словом, по логике поставить между словом и частицей уже нельзя. Если логика неверна, тоже укажите в ответе и скажите, как правильно. Окей, а если в предложении одно слово — «(Не)холодно», как тогда? То же со словом «тепло», «жарко» и тд. Ок, идем дальше.

Поговорим о «(не)важно». Например:

> Вы всегда видите одну сторону Луны, неважно, где находитесь.

Здесь, как я уже понял, слитно. Ок, а здесь «Мне это (не)важно (в значении «без разницы»)». Как тут? Или если тебя о чëм-то спрашивают, а ты отвечаешь «(Не)важно». Здесь как?

Переходим к «слышно».

> (Не)слышно, что ты говоришь.

По логике нужно писать так же, как и «важно», но можно поставить «было». Так как всë-таки?

> На улице не слышно людей.

Здесь можно поставить «было». А если это слово уже стоит перед «(не)слышно» в том же предложении, то слитно или нет? То же со словом «видно». И такие же вопросы к «интересно», «грустно», «больно» и другим СКС на «о».

Спасибо заранее! А, и ещë. Если предложение состоит из одного слова «(Не)слышно» в значении громкости звука, то?

Comment: Надо учиться на слух определять.

Comment: https://gramota.me/ne-slyishno-ili-neslyishno-kak-pishetsya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Розенталь (http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=74#pp74) в пункте 5 пишет: *Слова категории состояния на -о (так называемые предикативные наречия) пишутся с частицей не слитно при утверждении: нетрудно видеть и раздельно при отрицании: не трудно видеть (смысл обычно устанавливается самим пишущим).*

В примечании к этому пункту:

_Примечания 2. Различается написание частицы не с безлично-предикативными словами на -о и созвучными с ними краткими формами прилагательных и наречиями. Ср.:
Дать воды? — Не нужно. — Объяснение ненужно.
Существенных изменений не заметно. — Пятно незаметно. — Подал знак незаметно.

У Валгиной Н.С.(http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.57):

_Раздельно или слитно пишется не с наречиями при возможности двоякого толкования текста: до остановки недалеко (утверждение признака 'близко') — до остановки не далеко (отрицание признака 'далеко',т. е. 'не далеко и не близко'). То же характерно и для безлично-предикативных наречий типа нелегко рассказать ('трудно') — не легко рассказать ('и не трудно и не легко').

Примечание 2. Различается написание не с безлично-предикативными словами на о и созвучными с ними краткими прилагательными и наречиями; ср.: Серьезных отклонений не заметно (безлично-предикативное слово). — Отклонение от цели незаметно (краткое прилагательное). — Он незаметно приблизился к столу (наречие)._

Судя по этим рекомендациям, *не* пишется раздельно с предикативами.

На улице не холодно.

Вы всегда видите одну сторону Луны, не важно, где находитесь.

Не слышно, что ты говоришь.

На улице не слышно людей.

Мне не интересно (не грустно, не больно и другие СКС на «о»), что...

Не слышно.

*Холодно, грустно, интересно, больно* и другие созвучные с предикативами прилагательные и наречия пишутся с _не_слитно или раздельно  в зависимости от того, какой смысл в них вкладывает автор -- отрицание или утверждение.

На улице было не холодно -- здесь холодно является прилагательным, поэтому в зависимости от смысла нужно писать слитно (если утверждается, что было нехолодно, то есть тепло) или раздельно (если отрицается, что было холодно).

Comment: Ответ принимаю. Только абсолютно ВЕЗДЕ пишут «неважно» слитно, если предложение сложное. Но всë равно спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, для всех этих случаев одно правило: *Если это сказуемое, то раздельно.* (Грамота.ру) Тогда Ваши примеры:
*На улице не холодно*. Холодно - сказуемое.
*На улице было нехолодно*. Здесь сказуемое "было" - значит нехолодно слитно.
Приём со вставкой слова было, заключается в проверке - нехолодно сказуемое или нет? Если сказуемое уже есть , то и проверку проводить не зачем.
*Мне это не важно*. Правильно в любом смысле.
*Мне это не важно, а архиважно!* Тоже правильно.
Но *Мне всё стало неважно.*

*Не слышно, что ты говоришь* Это сложно подчиненное предложение. Первое предложение не полное - из одного сказуемого, значит пишется раздельно.
Слитно: *Ты говоришь неслышно*.

Comment: Подождите, в предложении «На улице было нехолодно» сказуемое не просто «было», а «было нехолодно» целиком. И нет разбора преложений, состоящих из одного слова — категории состояния.

Comment: Предпоследнее предложение ответа дает разбор и предложения из одного слова.  Можно было написать: *Не слышно - предложение не полное - из одного сказуемого, значит пишется раздельно.* Но это было бы лишним повтором, который любой редактор вычеркнет.

Comment: *...в предложении «На улице было нехолодно» сказуемое не просто «было», а «было нехолодно» целиком.* А что это меняет? Нехолодно и в  этом случае не сказуемое, а только его часть, значит и пишется слитно.